Questions about some tags: siphash, historic, integrity
Some unrelated questions about tags:

I see siphash has resurfaced. Its been created and removed before, I think I've done both at least once. Should it be kept this time? Should old questions about it be retagged?
I noticed historic has basically the same description as classical-cipher, except a bit broader. Should one be a synonym for the other?
What's up with integrity?


With 11 occurrences in questions [tag:siphash] looks OK to me as we have less used tags....

Well, I can't see any useful difference between historic and classical cipher.


yes and yes
I like the sound of classical-cipher and would make historic a synonym
Message integrity is a key application of cryptography, as such we probably want the tag, but I fear it may be overused.



I guess there might be "historic" questions that aren't about ciphers, but I didn't notice any in the currently tagged questions. 3. As I wrote in comments to a now deleted answer, by main problem with [tag:integrity] is that the excerpt is poor and gives no guidance when to use it.


Regarding historic, the main differences between that tag and classical-cipher are IMO twofold:

Some might argue that electromechanical ciphers like the Enigma don't really count as "classical ciphers," as the term is commonly used.  Then again, the opposite could be argued too.
Also arguably, classical ciphers may include "toy ciphers" that were never deployed historically.

I'm not convinced that these marginal differences really justify keeping the tags separate, but if we do merge them, we should at least take a closer look at these 11 questions first.  (Some of them might benefit from retagging with history instead of historic.)
Update: Some of those questions have since been retagged.  I think the remaining ones do fit under classical-cipher at least as well as they do under their current tags.  Thus, I'm now in favor of merging historic into classical-cipher (and have just suggested a tag synonym to that effect).

Since no one has chimed in against siphash, I've written a tag wiki and will tag the old questions where it's relevant.
